# Canon IR1024iF not scaning to shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, samba, network-share, server-message-block

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with shared folders for scanning. They work perfectly with the HP M4555 and Canon ir2025.

The problem is with a Canon iR1024iF, it fails to send the scanned file to the shared folder.

I have discarted permission problems, so I think is a problem with the samba protocol.

All the servers had been updated since the Wannacry thing but one old computer running Ubuntu 9 with a shared folder. The Canon iR1024iF is able to scan to this shared folder.

There is no new firmware for the Canon in the web, so what can I do?

Comment: It is hard to answer "it simply doesn't work"-type questions remotely. Maybe if you would ask "how to debug it", or "how to investigate", it would look better.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scan destination setting. Some canon model don't support the path correctly, especially in case like a share sub folder. If its your case, shorthen the path please.

Comment: I've checked it. It seems like the actual firmware it's not compatible with the SMB 2 protocol.

Comment: @miguelmald Iam not surprised.. their smb stack is poorly done, as like the bug I told about. maybe use an temporary destination to not enable smb1 on your server